# What is the best way to collapse an optional Grid Column at runtime?

Tags: silverlight, grid, runtime, mvvm-light, declarative

Currently I have a Grid with 6 optional fields, one on each row, in a data template bound to my view model.

6 Rows - 2 Columns

Column 0 has the label
Column 1 has the content associated with the label.

In this case I want to collapse the column when the Column 0 label is null.

My plan is to simply create a converter, if content is null, Height on the column will be 0 and call it good.

I'm assuming this is probably the easiest way.  I mean it's not hard, I just wonder if I'm missing a feature of the Grid.  Something I'm unaware of.. something declarative maybe.. ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could bind your grid to a collection, which doesn't include null column 0.